# How do do I embed text into a background image?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Sorry if the question is strange, I've only done a couple of small things in Python. Currently, I'm working on a choose your own adventure for a school project, and I want to make a GUI of sorts. I made backgrounds with spaces for text, and I'm now trying to find a way to create an imaginary text box embedded into the image where the text appears. Here is what I currently have:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()

    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=960, height=720)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('TitleScreen.png'))

    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tkinter.NW, image=image)
    canvas.pack()

    root.mainloop()

    text = tkinter.Label(root, text=(
    answer == input('You live in Valencia, Venezuela. You have 2 kids, and a significant other. You barely have enough '
            'money to take care of your family, food is running out, and electricity outages are a daily '
            'occurrence. Do you want to leave in search of a better life? [y/n]')
    if answer.lower().strip() == 'y':
        answer = input('Great, good decision. First should you prepare for the trip by buying supplies? [y/n]')
        if answer.lower().strip() == 'y' :
            print('Trick question there is a food shortage. Oh well, I guess you\'ll have to hope for the best.')
        elif answer.lower().strip() == 'n' :
            print('Cool. If your family starves to death just remember it is 100% your fault')
    # add option to restart

    answer = input('You hope to at least make it to Colombia first. Do you go to Araure [a] or Calabozo [b]?')
    if answer.lower().strip() == 'a' :
        Player = 1
    elif answer.lower().strip() == 'b' :
        Player = 2
    ))
text.pack()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
line 80
if answer.lower().strip() == 'y':
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `answer == input ...` – why compare instead of assign?

Comment: (Also your question title and introduction have little to do with the actual problem that you are encountering.)

Comment: usr2564301 I apologize, how could i better phrase it?

Comment: Also it does not work if I put just one equal sign

Comment: You cannot assign a code block to `text` option of `Label`.  Also everything beyond `root.mainloop()` will not be executed until `root` is destroyed.  So creating tkinter widget after `root.mainloop()` will raise error as `root` is already destroyed.